# Start plugin in subdirectory of workspace in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I clone a project from GIT to my workspace but I want the plugin I use (Ansible) to start in a subdirectory.

Given I have a structure like:

```
root-
    |
    --dir 1
    |
    --dir 2
```

I want the plugin to run in dir 2. (The ansible plugin seems to require the playbook to be in the root dir to work, correct me if I'm wrong. You can not specify a path to the playbook in the call to the plugin)

Comment: what is the task you want to perform in your remote server ? you can create the playbook where ever you want and run it using `ansible-playbook your-playbook.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify the path to the playbook as this:

```
${WORKSPACE}/dir2/playbook.yml
```

Which uses Jenkins' built-in variable to use the workspace path and then go relative from there.

That said, I've not used the Ansible plugin and we simply use a shell script in the Jenkins job that for some of our repos then `cd`s to the playbook root directory before calling the playbook like this:

```
cd path/to/playbook_root
ansible-playbook -i inventory/environment playbook.yml
```

This seems to work fine but I'm not sure if you get some added benefit from the Ansible plugin.